# How to update the attribute table in layer from dictionaries using python

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, qgis-2

I have dictionary with the values:

```
dict = {0L: {'val1': 60, 'val2': 199, 'val3': 7.719},1L: {'val1': 60, 'val2': 199, 'val3': 7.719}}
```

I want to update these values in the attribute table of a layer. How can i do that?

Comment: Hi, can you shortly explain the structure of your dictionary, in particular what the keys stand for. Please also provide information about what you have already tried.

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn 0L specifies the feature id and val1,val2,val3 are attribute fields. I have tried to convert dict to lists and then to update but that is a tedious process so searching for an solution to do it directly drom dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

1. Replace the attribute names with the corresponding field index
2. Update the features

   - On the vector layer by using `for fid, attrs in dict.iteritems():` and calling `layer.updateAttributeValue` repeatedly
   - On the dataprovider where a method `updateAttributeValues` exists which accepts a dict in the form `{fid: {attrIdx: value} }` as input parameter which is almost what you have.